# comparing two int arrays and printing out the difference

Tags: c#

> Duplicate question.

I'm trying to compare two int arrays that will look for the difference between them. Order is not important, and each array will not have duplicates within itself. For example, I've got:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 45, 26, 55, 99, 36 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 45, 26, 99, 20, 36 };
```

and I expect { 20, 55 } as a result.

Comment: Do you want to treat the arrays as sets or sequences? If your two arrays were `{ 1, 2, 3 }` and `{ 3, 2, 1 }` would you want to report the differences in the first and last elements, or not? Are the arrays always the same length?

Comment: You want to compare each element with the one in the same index in the other array or position is irrelevant and you want the elements that are in one and not in the other? Depending on your answer is either Daisy or D-Shih answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use linq `Except` to get different from two arrays, then use `Union` combine two arrays.

```
var result1 = arr2.Except(arr1);
var result2 = arr1.Except(arr2);
var result = result1.Union(result2);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tk7q2U)

Comment: Maybe. That will treat the inputs like sets rather than sequences... it's not quite clear what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently comparing every element in `arr1` with every element in `arr2`. You want to compare them pair-wise instead, by the looks of it. (Although the question is slightly unclear.)

If you want code that only uses simple aspects of the language, you could do this simply like this:

```
// TODO: Check that arr1.Length and arr2.Length are the same
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Difference at element {0}: {1} != {2}", i, arr1[i], arr2[i]);
    }
}
```

With LINQ you could do this using `Zip` instead (and tuples, and interpolated string literals...):

```
var differences = arr1.Zip(arr2, (x, y) => (x, y))
                      .Where(p => p.x != p.y);
foreach (var pair in differences)
{
    // We don't have the index at this point
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.x} != {pair.y}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Daisy. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @ChrisH.: In that case I'm confused as to why you've accepted the other answer, which doesn't do the same thing. If the other answer works for you, then this one won't, and vice versa...